# Scrollview not scrolling to the bottom inside ViewAnimator

Tags: android, uiscrollview, android-scrollview, viewanimator

The view shown below belongs to a login and chat Fragment *(probably a bad design idea, but works nicely for our purpose)* the ScrollView inside the second LinearLayout scrolls when a new message is sent trough:

```
 scroll = (ScrollView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scrollView_chat);
 //scroll.scrollTo(0, scroll.getBottom()); doesn't work either
 scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Both ways of scrolling produce the same result: The View **scrolls but never to the bottom, so the last message sent is not visible.**

This is the *infamous* view:

```
<ViewAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/right_side_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/username_text"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="@string/username_hint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext|flagNoExtractUi"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/password_text"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password_text"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/password_text"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext|flagNoExtractUi"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/login_button"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/login_button"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/username_text"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="18dp"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/password_text"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/create_new_account"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/create_new_account"
        android:theme="@style/PrimaryButton"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/create_new_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/create_new_account"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/login_button"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarLogin"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/status_text"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_chat"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="80">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:id="@+id/chatOutputText" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/swag">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chatInputText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:enabled="false"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_chat_message_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:theme="@style/PrimaryButtonOval"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ViewAnimator>
```

Any idea of what could be wrong here?